# One web service per module, or one web service overall?

Tags: .net, apache-flex, web-services

I'm doing a flex application that has tons of screens (each very different, can't reuse :( ), and tons of web methods in .net.

is it correct to create one .asmx per module, or should I stick to one big .asmx

Would there be connection or IIS problems?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would arrange it how it makes the most sense to you. I don't think there would be any problems with IIS either way.

If you go with one big .asmx, that is going to be ONE BIG .asmx.

Comment: I would prefer doing one asmx per screen, but I think IIS would create one connection per web service instead of just one overall. I really don't know and can't find answers.

Comment: IIS will create one connection per request, unless keep alive is set on the request. Then it should create one connection per server, no matter how many .asmx files you have.