# Multiple dedicated web services or one centralized web service?[.net]

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, architecture

Explaining the scenario: We currently have the task to create a Web Service architecture and design approach to handle an enterprise level business. Just imagine we have only one centralized web site system with more than a thousands of pages and more than 300 tables (more than 500 dbo overall) in one of our databases. 
So we are thinking in modularizing this structure and taking it to a web service approach for several devices (multi-platform).
I have read in details this other questions:

[Data Access Layer as a web service -- Is this a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508746/data-access-layer-as-a-web-service-is-this-a-good-idea)

[Web Service or WebServices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017618/web-service-or-webservices)

[One web service per module, or one web service overall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065811/one-web-service-per-module-or-one-web-service-overall)

among others. But I need to be accurate in this decision because this is an enterprise level issue. So I need to compare this two options in terms of some of the following Software "-ilities" topics:

1-Scalability

2-Maintainability

3-Security **

4-Extensibility

And finally but not less important: Performance **(this is crucial)

I'm open to suggestions other than this approach if anyone has really better ideas in terms of real facts and previous experience. I also would like to hear detailed explanations (I don't mind reading too much)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend going with microservices architecture. It is closer to “One web service per module” solution. If you have a solid CI process microservices will ease your development process.  This architecture is Scalable, Maintainable, Secure, Extensible and Performant. However, all these should be built into framework that you may build for your enterprise level solution. Now the question is how to implement? This depends on the choice of platform.

**Microsoft Azure:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-overview-microservices

**Amazon Web Services:** https://aws-de-media.s3.amazonaws.com/images/AWS_Summit_Berlin_2016/sessions/pushing_the_boundaries_1300_microservices_on_aws.pdf

I trying to keep it brief here as I do not know which platform you intend to implement  your solution on and there is a lot you can read about microservices, just google microservices. If you have specific questions on implementation let me know I can help.

Comment: I was reading both articles and it seems like a promising approach, this architecture is quite advanced but what about handling this in and standalone Windows Server with limited resources in the hardware side (not so bad but limited). And what about the design of the DAL for common consumption on those microservices using ADO.Net and Data Entity and the same business Class domain. Is this a correct approach or should we change the whole design?? I mean is it correct if those services run on the same server consuming the same DLLs because this looks to me like a very independent architecture.

Comment: I think this will work even on standalone windows server, with virtualization this is not impossible to implement. But it may be effort intensive. Using Azure or AWS will make it easier. I would take this decision based on budget for the project, the number of servers on hand, the load the application has to support and the structure of development team (small teams works best).  I would not make DAL as separate microservice, I believe DAL layer as service will become a macroservice that becomes too big to manage, and every service will have dependency on it, I would avoid it.

Comment: So you recommend implementation of DAL for each service. What about the common or similar CRUD tasks? Lets say I'm trying to get information to build one object from to modules but this information could be retrieved from one GET DAL process. Do you recommend calling two or more services with different DAL layers?

Comment: Yes. When deployed, each service should have its own DAL layer. All CRUD operations in DAL can be written in DAL base implementation(a framework of sort) using Generics. If any of the microservices need any specialized DAL operations they can be written in the respective microservice's DAL layer.